Flutter app icon is broken, how can I fix it?
My app icon is broken and I don't know why but it is black for android and it is different for ios like picture can anyone help me for this issue, I tried to recreate the app icon but it does not worked
flutter_launcher_icons: 
   android: "launcher_icon" 
   ios: true 
   image_path: "assets/icon/app_icon.png" 
   min_sdk_android: 21


To resolve app icon for real value

Make sure the assets path is ok,
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.14.1

flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  web:
    generate: true
  windows:
    generate: true
  macos:
    generate: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon.png"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/icon.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "#ffffff"

And run
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main

or
dart run flutter_launcher_icons:generate

Also do a flutter clean and rebuild the app.

Clean Flutter and try again!
flutter clean

flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main


For the black icon appearing on Android, the suggestion of @WhistlerChoi on this GitHub thread worked for me. Basically, declare adaptive_icon_background and adaptive_icon_foreground similar to the attached image below. Please note that the adaptive_icon_foreground is the path to your icon image.

